# Configurable outputDirectory for maven war plugin using Git

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I have put up a maven project on git repository which is using maven-war-plugin to create war directly in tomcat directory. But on different systems, tomcat directory path can be different.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory><file-path></outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I want this outputDirectory parameter to be configurable without needing to change pom.xml on local systems.

Comment: You can try using properties (users will have their own values in their user `settings.xml`) or use environment variables

Comment: Check out the answer by @EricGreg in this SO post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463077/how-to-refer-environment-variable-in-pom-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [ali4j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062407/ali4j) mentioned in comment, using env variable is appropriate solution for this scenario. Use a custom env variable in POM and ask the users to set the env in their system.
[How to refer environment variable in POM.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463077/how-to-refer-environment-variable-in-pom-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue and I resolved it by putting the below plugin in my POM file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>                            
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>  


<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

Comment: This is good solution but it mandates to keep configurable resource inside project directory. The environment variable seems apt solution.