# How to setup environment variables in test scope with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I need to setup some environment variables in my test classes and I don't want to pass them to Maven with `-D` flag every time. Is there a way to setup these environment variables in `pom.xml` file only for tests?

I've tried to setup them with `System.getenv().put()` but without success (`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`)

Comment: you can specify env variables in pom instead of using -D . this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463077/how-to-refer-environment-variable-in-pom-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most maven plugins seem to support the configuration element.  This should explain what you need
[Configuring surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html)