# Pass "non D" parameter to jenkins maven build step

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a couple of "Invoke top-level Maven targets" build steps in a project being build by Jenkins.

In the "Properties" field you can specify an arbitray amount of maven build parameters like

`skipTests=true` evaluating to `-DskipTests=true`

However I want to pass a build parameter that must not be preceded by -D and also does not require an equals sign.
Like `-Psomething`.

Is there any way to do this using the "Invoke top-level Maven targets" or do I need to trigger the mvn build manually via "Execute shell"?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a field for profile activations?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware of. I ended up using a bash script instead of the maven build step.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to passing properties is to set environment variables and read them. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463077/how-to-refer-environment-variable-in-pom-xml).

Another workaround is by using a profile. Basically in following example you will have to set environment variable RUNTESTS to true to activate your profile and you can do the intended tasks inside this profile (e.g. running junits conditionally.):

```
<profile>
            <id>runtests</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.RUNTESTS</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <finalName>re</finalName>
                <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>default-test</id>
                                    <phase>test</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Profile can be specified in the goals section, e.g.

```
clean install -Psomething
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).