# pass dockerfile arguments to a pom.xml

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to pass docker file ARGS, to a pom file?

I have a docker file with `ARG USER=foo` and I wanted to use the argument from the dockerfile in a pom.xml with something similar to `<username>${docker.args.USER}</username>`.  I only need them at run time for a build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker `ARG`s are added to your image as environment variables, so you should be able to load them in to your pom.xml in the same way as other environment variables.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10463133/2618764, it looks like you can use `${env.USER}` to get what you need.

If that doesn't work for you, can you post your dockerfile and pom.xml?

Comment: I had to use an `arg user=foo` & `env user= ${user}` then ${env.USER} worked