# Pass Jenkins credentials to Maven Surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, credentials

**Use Case**

I am developing a templated pipeline solution so teams can build, test and scan their projects consistently with every job run in Jenkins. One of these projects uses Maven for dependency management and requires passing Jenkins credentials so integration tests can be run.

**Examples**

Passing credentials via command line arguments works just fine. For example...

```
withCredentials([
    [
        $class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 
        credentialsId: 'TEST', 
        usernameVariable: 'TEST_USERNAME', 
        passwordVariable: 'TEST_PASSWORD'
    ]
]) {
    sh 'mvn clean install -D test_username=$TEST_USERNAME -D test_password=$TEST_PASSWORD'
}
```

I'd strongly prefer to pass these variables to the underlying plugins via each respective plugin's configuration (namely the Maven Surefire plugin). The justification for this preferred approach is to utilize a structured method to manage system properties. I've tried a number of methods including passing arguments by setting the `<argLines>` element of the Surefire configuration and setting the `<systemPropertyValues>` element, but neither method is working. Also, it's preferred to reference these properties via a YAML file to achieve externalized configuration, but I am not opposed to other methods of accessing this information **if it's impossible to reference credential variables in a configuration file**.

*pom.xml*

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Tacking 'env.' to the beginning of each variable name does not make a difference; tests still fail. -->
        <argLines>-D test_username=${TEST_USERNAME} -D test_password=${TEST_PASSWORD}</argLines>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <test_username>${TEST_USERNAME}</test_username>
            <test_username>${TEST_PASSWORD}</test_username>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*bootstrap-test.yaml*

```yaml
datasource:
    jdbc_url: *omitted*
    username: ${test_username}
    password: ${test_password}
```

**Results**

If I try to run the tests in the Jenkins environment by specifying system properties in the configuration section, then the tests fail. As an aside I am passing these credentials off to Spring Boot, but the `entityManagerFactory` (`org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`) fails to initialize.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/acme/Config.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
```

I fear the issue might be due to Spring Boot's inability to access obfuscated credentials, or trying to access system properties within a configuration file too late in Maven's lifecycle.

I am also not entirely opposed to passing system properties via command line, but the templated solution will need to include an effective (secure) way to round up different credential types to pass off to the Maven invocation.

---

**UPDATE 1**:

Running this project locally (on a Windows machine, by the way) after exporting the variables does in fact work, but does **not work** in Jenkins. The method that worked locally involved setting either the environment or system property variables in the Surefire plugin configuration section. I did prefix references to environment variables created by Jenkins with `env.`.

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Using the Maven antrun plugin I was able to echo the masked secrets exported by Jenkins.

Comment: Have you tried storing them as "secrets" in Jenkins? I did this for unencrypting encrypted files in my application. I think if you store them as (for instance) "MAVEN_PWD" you should be able to retrieve them at runtime.

Comment: @hfontanez Yes, and the tests still fail to resolve the externalized variables. How did you access those variables in the project you mentioned? Command line arguments, Surefire plugin configuration, etc.?

Comment: #1 Are you using scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline? #2 Java frameworks like maven don't care how jenkins manage its variables. Usually those use environment variables to avoid hardcoded values.  Is there an option for you, the use of environment variables?

Comment: @JRichardsz I am using a declarative pipeline and open to using environment variables.

Comment: @MikeDeitrick unfortunately I do not remember and I am no longer employed at the place where I did this. But, I think JRichardsz is into something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on a fresh jenkins and it works as expected. If plugin(java class) is able to read environment variables and jenkins inject environment variables, everything should work.

I think your error is the environment variable syntax. Accoding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10463133/3957754) you should use **${env.VARIABLE_NAME}** to use **environment variables** in a pom.xml. So in your case, your pom.xml should be like this:

```
<test_username>${env.TEST_USERNAME}</test_username>
<test_username>${env.TEST_PASSWORD}</test_username>
```

And then inject the required variables with

```
withCredentials([
    [
        $class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 
        credentialsId: 'TEST', 
        usernameVariable: 'TEST_USERNAME', 
        passwordVariable: 'TEST_PASSWORD'
    ]
]) {
    sh 'mvn clean install'
}
```

#### Java system properties and environment variables

When you use `-Dmykey = value` on any java implementation, you are setting a System property, **not an environment variable**. Check this:

- [Java system properties and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I tried adding new properties in the main properties section of the pom.xml that reference the environment variable (i.e. `<secret>${env.SECRET}</secret>`) but now I'm seeing a slightly different error. It seems the test configuration (bootstrap-test.yaml) is viewing `"${secret}"` (with or without double quotes) as a literal value and not performing any string interpolation. I realize this is now a completely different concern from my original question. I want to say the method you described will work, but I'm not sure...

Comment: you could try without jenkins.  Injecting the env var direct on the shell with `export TEST_USERNAME=john` , then in your pom.xml `${env.TEST_USERNAME}`, the running your maven command, directly on the shell : `mvn clean package`. If it works, with jenkins will work. If not works in the shell, will not work on jenkins.

Comment: Interesting findings based on your suggestions... running this project locally (on a Windows machine, by the way) after exporting the variables does in fact work, but does **not** work in Jenkins. The method that worked locally involved setting either the environment or system property variables in the Surefire plugin configuration section. I did prefix references to environment variables created by Jenkins with `env.`. I'll update my question based on these findings.

Comment: Added one more update about verifying Jenkins environment variables through the Maven antrun plugin.

Comment: Really bizarre finding - I was originally calling Maven with `mvn clean install -f ./pom.xml...`, as folks have the ability to adjust where their POM is located (but encouraged to follow Maven conventions). It turns out something really weird was happening when passing './pom.xml' to Maven, but 'pom.xml' actually manages to resolve the environment variables perfectly fine. I have no clue why this is happening, but I'm going to accept your answer as it logically makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly bizarre, but how one specifies the POM location seems to make a difference. Originally I was supplying `-f ./pom.xml` to Maven and the environment variables could not be resolved. On a complete whim I supplied `f pom.xml` (no './') and the environment variables where resolved successfully.

Unfortunately I have no idea why this makes a difference, but will update my answer if I manage to uncover more details down the road...

Comment: explanation: Microsoft Windows. Thanks to divine providence, the real servers are Linux <3