Create jib container image in compile phase, and pushing the same image in the deploy phase
I am building a container image using maven Jib plugin, and it is building fine. I can push it to repository as well. But I am having an issue in figuring iut how to build the image on compile phase, then pushing it to repo on deploy phase, without having to build it again.
Do I need to rewrite the plugin configs two time and jib will have the image cached, so it wont build it again? Or is there some documentation I am missing from github.
I tried building image and pushing it in one phase.
I need to build it in one phase, and push that image in a different phase

Hi @houssam! I have similar problem. Well, I have 2 of them. First of all, I want to do what you described. But I couldn't find out how it should be done. So, if you managed to get a solution for that, please do not hesitate to share that with us. :-)
Secondly, jib works fine from local, but it can't push image from Jenkins pipeline. I use exactly the same settings.xml on local and in Jenkins as well. Have you seen similar?

You need to use a single execution in the package or deploy phase to both build and push an image. I don't even know if both action can be split in two executions as Jib does not work that way.
Here is a sample configuration of mine:
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>${jib-maven-plugin.goal}</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <!--
                      Use the tagged version of JDK to ensure consistent build.
                      The image must have the target architecture (configuration.from.platforms.platform.architecture) among the manifest list.
                      See: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-specify-a-platform-in-the-manifest-list-or-oci-index-of-a-base-image
                    -->
                    <image>openjdk:17.0.1-jdk-slim@sha256:9a37f2c649301b955c2fd31fb180070404689cacba0f77404dd20afb1d7b8d84</image>
                    <platforms>
                        <platform>
                            <architecture>amd64</architecture>
                            <os>linux</os>
                        </platform>
                    </platforms>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>${jib-maven-plugin.to.image}</image>
                    <!--
                      The credentials are required to connect to a remote Docker repository.
                      Environment variables like `PATH` and `M2_HOME` are referenced using the env.* prefix, so define only
                      See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10463133/3764965
                      See: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html
                    -->
                    <auth>
                        <username>${env.HARBOR_USERNAME}</username>
                        <password>${env.HARBOR_PASSWORD}</password>
                    </auth>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                    </tags>
                </to>
                <container>
                    <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                    <mainClass>com.myapp.Application</mainClass>
                    <user>nobody</user>
                    <workingDirectory>/app/resources</workingDirectory>
                </container>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

It needs modifications. Please, refer to the Jib Maven Plugin documentation for more details: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin
Variables:

jib-maven-plugin.goal:

Localhost Docker repository: Use dockerBuild for a build with and push it into a local Docker daemon.
Remote Docker repository: Use build goal for a dockerless build and pushing to a remote Docker repository.


jib-maven-plugin.to.image:

Localhost Docker repository: Use simply a name of the application, such as myapp.
Remote Docker repository: Use a full path including the domain to represent an image address in the remote Docker repository, for example, imagine.mycompany.com/mydepartment/myproject/myapp



Here are a few tips:

Use a tagged version of JDK for consistent builds.
Use credentials from the environment variables for deploying to Docker Harbor or any image artifactory.

