# remote debugging with maven tomcat and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, tomcat

The same "old question", I am pretty new to Maven and I can not figure out why in the end I am getting a message like "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused." from Eclipse.

Maven options (I've set this environment variable on my `~/.profile` `~/.bashrc` etc.)

```
$ echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

On Eclipse I've set a Debug profile on a `Remote Java Application` based on the project I want to debug, with host `127.0.0.1` (not `localhost` because the Maven profile `dev` I am using, see below, is explicitly setting that IP address) and port `8000`.

Then when I run the application from the command line with the following command (maven is picking a `dev` profile from the pom file):

```
$ mvn tomcat:run -P dev
```

and I start Eclipse in debug mode on the Eclipse Remote Java Application profile I previously set I am getting a message from an Eclipse popup window saying:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused
```

I suspect the settings from the `$MAVEN_OPTS` are not pick up from some reason, have a look at the following output from the `ps` command:

```
USER_NAME@my-laptop $ ps aux | grep tomcat
USER_NAME   16526 11.3 13.7 3014276 500680 pts/5  Sl+  11:25   0:29 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher tomcat:run -P dev
```

More details:

- java version "1.7.0_25"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
- Eclipse Kepler

Please shed some light, thanks and again... Apologies for the dummy question.

Answer (score 4):

The docs for [tomcat:run](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html) describe the systemProperties value that you can put in the pom.xml file.

The settings that you have above would look like this in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <JAVA_OPTS>-Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000</JAVA_OPTS>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929890/274350).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a parameter, try adding `-Xdebug` to your MAVEN_OPTS

Also see: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1