# Getting "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file" upon executing JaCoCo

Tags: maven, junit, jacoco

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, JUnit 4.8.1, and Jacoco 0.6.3.201306030806, and I am trying to create test coverage reports.

I have a project with unit tests only, but I can't get reports to run, I'm repeatedly getting the error: `Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file` when I run:

```
mvn clean install -P test-coverage
```

Here is how my pom is configured:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <argLine>-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
<profile>
  <id>test-coverage</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
        <configuration>
          <destfile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destfile>
          <datafile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</datafile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <propertyName>itCoverageAgent</propertyName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

All my tests run successfully. Here is some of the output from Maven:

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.2.201302030002:prepare-agent (prepare-unit-tests) @ myproject ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.2.201302030002/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.2.201302030002-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
    ...
Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
    ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.2.201302030002:prepare-agent (prepare-integration-tests) @ myproject ---
[INFO] itCoverageAgent set to -javaagent:/Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.2.201302030002/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.2.201302030002-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/target/jacoco.exec 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14.1:integration-test (default) @ myproject ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MacRoman, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14.1:verify (default) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MacRoman, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.2.201302030002:report (jacoco-site) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file
[INFO]
```

Any ideas what configuration I'm missing?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269558/maven-jacoco-plugin-error

Comment: Seems you also have integration tests in your pom, which might be a distraction. Also, we stripped out the `destFile` and let it write to default target/jacoco.exec file.

Comment: I have posted answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304793/jacoco-with-maven-missing-execution-data-file/55744041#55744041) location.

Comment: A very [good explanation and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305148/2331225) that solved problem for me.

Answer (score 218):

### jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.10-SNAPSHOT

From [jacoco:prepare-agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html) that says:

> One of the ways to do this in case of maven-surefire-plugin - is to
>   use syntax for late property evaluation:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>   <configuration>
>     <argLine>@{argLine} -your -extra -arguments</argLine>
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

Note the `@{argLine}` that's added to `-your -extra -arguments`.

Thanks [Slava Semushin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352708/slava-semushin) for noticing the change and [reporting in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107375/getting-skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-file-upon-exec/23605812?noredirect=1#comment73102702_23605812).

### jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT

Following [jacoco:prepare-agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html) that says:

> *[org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:prepare-agent]* Prepares a property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent that can be
>   passed as a VM argument to the application under test. Depending on
>   the project packaging type by default a property with the following
>   name is set:
>
> - tycho.testArgLine for packaging type eclipse-test-plugin and
> - argLine otherwise.
>
> Note that these properties must not be overwritten by the
>   test configuration, otherwise the JaCoCo agent cannot be attached. If
>   you need custom parameters please append them. For example:
>
> ```
> <argLine>${argLine} -your -extra -arguments</argLine>
> ```
>
> Resulting
>   coverage information is collected during execution and by default
>   written to a file when the process terminates.

you should change the following line in `maven-surefire-plugin` plugin configuration from (note the `${argLine}` inside `<argLine>`):

```
<argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
```

to

```
<argLine>${argLine} -Xmx2048m</argLine>
```

Make also the necessary changes to the other plugin `maven-failsafe-plugin` and replace the following (again, notice the `${argLine}`):

```
<argLine>-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
```

to

```
<argLine>${argLine} -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
```

Comment: Now though, theres [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190107/cannot-use-jacoco-jvm-args-and-surefire-jvm-args-together-in-maven) problem, without the jacoco target, the build fails.

Comment: Worked for but I had to use tycho.testArgLine since I am using tycho.

Comment: Actually, it worked on my local machine but now travis CI shows an error: `Error: Could not find or load main class ${ui.test.vmargs}`.

Comment: OK, fixed it by only having one variable substitution on the `argLine`.

Comment: The quoted link now has a bit different suggestion to use `@{argLine}`.

Comment: Exactly this was my issue. I had custom arguments in mvn command `mvn clean package sonar:sonar -U -DargLine="-Dxxx=yyy"`. I am not declaring maven-surefire-plugin explicitly and setting configurations. I just add argLine placeholder in the maven command line like

`mvn clean package sonar:sonar -U -DargLine="@{argLine} -Dxxx=yyy"`. Now jacoco.exec file is generated and coverage report is generated in sonar.

Comment: It works !!! The problem was due to an <argLine> configuration I added on maven-surefire-plugin in order to increase memory for Integration tests

Configuring <argLine>${argLine} --my--additional-arguments--here-- </argLine> solved the problem

Comment: This kind of change caused the following problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272870/surefire-maven-plugin-corrupted-stdout-by-directly-writing-to-native-stream-in .

Comment: If using <argLine> this is the way to go. Saved me :)

Comment: works also for  version:: 0.8.7

Answer (score 46):

I faced a bit of a different issue that returned the same error.

```
Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data /target/jacoco.exec
```

The truth is, this error is returned for many, many reasons.
We experimented with the different solutions on Stack Overflow, but found this [resource](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719060500/www.ffbit.com/blog/2014/05/21/skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-file/) to be best. It tears down the many different potential reasons why Jacoco could be returning the same error.

For us, the solution was to add a prepare-agent to the configuration.

```
<execution>
   <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
   <goals>
       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
   </goals>
</execution>
```

I would imagine most users will be experiencing it for different reasons, so take a look at the aforementioned resource!

Comment: I think you nailed it. People may google it for a "quick fix", but the most correct answer would be "The truth is, this error is returned for many, many reasons". Just need to find out what that is. For me, it was a parent pom overwriting the <argLine> in the maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: This! Thanks. I got the same message, but it was because my surefire plugin was only looking for files named `**/*Test.java` when my test classes were named `*Tests.java`

Comment: I had two problems:

1. No test classes whatsoever, need at least one `*Test.java` class, and one test method annotated with `@Test` so Jacoco can do something.
2. In Travis environment variables for my project, had typo in `SONART_TOKEN=*****`, should have been named `SONAR_TOKEN=*****`. See Travis docs [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/), search for `or define SONAR_TOKEN in your Repository Settings`.
After I fixed that, build ran successfully. [You may view my gitbhub project in question](https://github.com/joquijada/code-quality-maven-plugin).

Comment: Link now goes to a questionable content farm.

Comment: Use archive.org for link - https://web.archive.org/web/20190719060500/www.ffbit.com/blog/2014/05/21/skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-file/

Comment: THANKS! I updated the link. You rock!

Answer (score 33):

One can also get "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file" error due to missing tests in project. For example when you fire up new project and have no *Test.java files at all.

Comment: This is gold ! Helped me

Answer (score 19):

There might a case where some other argline setup or plugin in pom may be overriding jacoco execution order setup.

argLine set to -`javaagent:/Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.2.201302030002/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.2.201302030002-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/target/jacoco.exec`

One of the example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>5</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After getting rid of argLine from these plugins, jacoco started to work normally.

Comment: Note the forkcount!

Answer (score 11):

> When using the maven-surefire-plugin or maven-failsafe-plugin you must not use a forkCount of 0 or set the forkMode to never as this would prevent the execution of the tests with the javaagent set and no coverage would be recorded.

ref: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

this is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/caliburn1994/253966dec3ece0c020ebb8ab863124b9)

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is pretty old but if someone like me comes here looking for an answer then this might help. I have been able to overcome the above error with this.

1) Remove the below piece of code from the plugin maven-surefire-plugin

```
 <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
 <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
```

2) Add the below goal:

```
<execution>
<id>default-prepare-agent</id>
<goals>
   <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 7):

I've tried all answers but only the following combination of advice has worked for me. Why? I had very specific requirements:

1. JaCoCo generates report when build is run from command line: `mvn clean verify` (Maven 3.6.0)
2. Intellij IDEA (2019.01) runs my tests as well
3. It all works in presence of another `javaagent` defined in `surefire` plugin

**Solution** - prepend `argLine` value in `surefire` configuration with "late replacement" maven property `@{...}` as explained in `surefire` [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation) ([my fixed configuration](https://github.com/ableneo/liferay-db-setup-core/commit/1fcd832678ad92c059acced6122c96fca6504dee))

> How do I use properties set by other plugins in argLine?
>   Maven does property replacement for
>
> ${...}
>   values in pom.xml before any plugin is run. So Surefire would never see the place-holders in its argLine property.
>   Since the Version 2.17 using an alternate syntax for these properties,
>
> @{...}
>   allows late replacement of properties when the plugin is executed, so properties that have been modified by other plugins will be picked up correctly.

*Failed first try - [define jaCoCoArgLine](https://github.com/ableneo/liferay-db-setup-core/commit/1fcd832678ad92c059acced6122c96fca6504dee) property in `prepare-agent` goal configuration of `jacoco` - the scenario failed my second requirement, IntelliJ IDEA couldn't figure out agent for jmockit I use in the project for static method mocking*

Comment: Faced the same problem when using with JMockit and was able to resolve the issue with this solution. i.e adding argLine in surefire plugin

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. I updated the Jacoco version from 0.6 to 0.8 and updated surefire plugin as well. The following command generated Jacoco reports in site/jacoco/ folder:

```
mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent install jacoco:report
```

My maven configurations are as follows:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-report</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                    </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>PACKAGE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.0</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>60</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Note the forkcount!

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me, but can you elaborate a bit on why you have the forkcount configuration, and the forkedProcessExitTimeOut?

Answer (score 5):

Came accross the same problem just now.

I have a class named `HelloWorld`, and I created a test class for it named `HelloWorldTests`, then I got the output `Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.`

I then tried to change my `pom.xml` to make it work, but the attempt failed.

Finally, I simply rename `HelloWorldTests` to `HelloWorldTest`, and it worked!

So I guess that, **by default**, jacoco only recognizes test class named like `XxxTest`, which indicates that it's the test class for `Xxx`. So simply rename your test classes to this format should work!

Answer (score 4):

FWhat tdrury said:

change your plugin configuration into this:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
        <executions>
          <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Edit:
Just noticed one important thing, destFile and dataFile seems case sensitive so it's supposed to be destFile, not destfile.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
mvn jacoco:report -debug
```

to see the details about your reporting process.

I configured my jacoco like this:

```
<configuration>
    <dataFile>~/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
    <outputDirectory>~/jacoco</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Then `mvn jacoco:report -debug` shows it using the default configuration, which means `jacoco.exec` is not in `~/jacoco.exec`. The error says `missing execution data file`.

So just use the default configuration:

```
<execution>
    <id>default-report</id>
    <goals>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

And everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled for days. I tried all the different configurations suggested in this thread. None of them works. Finally, I find only the important configuration is the **prepare-agent** goal. But you have to put it in the right phase. I saw so many examples put it in the "*pre-integration-test*", that's a misleading, as it will only be executed after unit test. So the unit test won't be instrumented.

The right config should just use the default phase, (don't specify the phase explicitly). And usually, you don't need to mass around *maven-surefire-plugin*.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-site</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

Jacoco Execution data file is a **jacoco.exec** file which is generated when prepare agent goal is running. When It isn't generated or the correct path isn't set in configuration, you will get that error message. Because Jacoco use It to build test coverage. This usually occur when you use jacoco maven plugin and surfire or failsafe. To ensure that the jacoco.exec file is generated, you have to add argline in you pom.xml file, not in the surfire configuration but inside a properties tag in you pom.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
</properties>
```

Comment: 1st answer where I found an explanation as well about what the error means.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but just for anyone else who has this issue and nothing seems to fix it (like I had). Make sure that in you pom, your configuration for jacoco inside `plugins` is not in turn inside `pluginManagement`. It seems some sort of default for maven is to put the `plugins` inside `pluginManagement`. This is almost unnoticeable until you try to add detailed configurations like for jacoco. In order to add these, you need to add them outside of the `pluginManagement`, otherwise they are effectively ignored. See my poms below for details.

My old pom (that gave the "Skipping jacoco ..." message):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>default-report</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

My new pom (that now compiles a working jacoco report):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>default-report</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

**2 Other Possibilities**

JaCoCo's Maven plugin could be better integrated with Maven to provide more information about it's invocation and incorrect invocations.  Nonetheless.

### Possibility #1: Custom Arguments In Surefire plugin

Using JPMS module for my project with standard Maven directory layout, basic JSE 11 program, JUnit 5 & JaCoCo, with Eclipse and single `module-info.java` file (Eclipse 4.13 won't allow 2 `module-info.java` files in the project's root of the classpath).  In order for Surefire to see my test cases I had to use the single `<argLine>` tag to allow Surefire to gain access using: `--add-opens` for all of the packages having unit tests:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <argLine>
         @{argLine}
         --add-opens module_name/com.myco.project=ALL-UNNAMED
         --add-opens module_name/com.myco.project.more=ALL-UNNAMED
         --add-opens module_name/com.myco.project.others=ALL-UNNAMED
      </argline>
   </configuration>
   ...
</plugin>
```

According to Jacoco documentation, you have to directly pass the Jacoco arguments to Surefire since specifying any Surefire arguments using `<argLine>` overrides Jacoco's defaults.  Jacoco's online Maven documentation specifies using `@{argLine}` to pass Jacoco's arguments to Surefire (https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html).

### Possibility #2: Intermingling Plugins

I also use the `maven-javadoc` plugin in my `<reporting/>` section.  Incidentally, during the Javadoc reporting phase, it manages to invoke the `prepare-agent` goal of JaCoCo and gives the OP's error message shortly thereafter (according to maven debug, specifically while the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` is configuring the reports to begin generating for maven `site`) - this despite the fact that my Test phase has already run and dumped a proper `jacoco.exec` file in the build output directory.  It may be safe to ignore this warning, my JaCoCo report renders fine in my Maven Site.  However, if you're seeing it during the execution of a JaCoCo goal, it probably shouldn't be ignored.

### Tips

If you're having doubts about the file getting created, watch the directory where the file is supposed to appear during the build.  Generating the file is a fairly slow process.  See my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465187/2336934

Do your best to keep to all the defaults as much as possible, simpler is better.

Answer (score 2):

The execution says it's putting the jacoco data in /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/target/jacoco.exec but your maven configuration is looking for the data in ${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec.

Comment: Right, so why is the plugin ignoring what I specify in the configuration?

Comment: try moving your destfile configuration into the configuration of the prepare-agent execution.  Not all maven plugins graciously handle configuration inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

It happens if the path of your project has blank spaces anywhere, such as:

`/home/user/my projects/awesome project`

the report is not generated. If that is the case, remove those spaces from directory names, such as:

`/home/user/my-projects/awesome-project`

or move the project to a directory that doesn't have spaces along the way.

About the plugin configuration, I just needed the basic as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>       
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a [Maven/Java project](https://github.com/johan974/spring_unittest_or_integrationtest_findbugs_jacoco) with 1 Domain class with the following features:

- **Unit or Integration testing** with the plugins Surefire and Failsafe.
- Findbugs.
- Test coverage via **Jacoco**.

Where are the Jacoco results? After testing and running 'mvn clean', you can find the results in 'target/site/jacoco/index.html'. Open this file in the browser.

Enjoy!

I tried to keep the project as simple as possible. The project puts many suggestions from these posts together in an example project. **Thank you, contributors!**

Comment: I tried your git project but it is not clear that how to see the report.

Comment: Where are the Jacoco results? After testing and running 'mvn clean', you can find the results in 'target/site/jacoco/index.html'. Open this file in the browser.

Comment: You might want to link your repository back to stackoverflow. I had a hard time finding the question again after I found a bug in your demo.

Comment: And still does not work as expected :-( the target directory has only aggregate.exec as it's content when doing mvn clean install ...

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error because tests execution were skipped.

I ran my build with similar system parameter : `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true`

Turning this system parameter to `false` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My response is very late but for others users 
In your case you have to configure failsafe pluging to use the command line agent configuration saved in itCoverageAgent variable.
For exemple

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
</configuration>
```

In your maven configuration, jacoco prepare the command line arguments in prepare-agent phase, but failsafe plugin doesn't use it so there is no execution data file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the execution runs first time, and when we do maven clean install it doesn't generate after that.
The issue was using true for skipMain and skip properties 
under maven-compiler-plugin of the main pom File.
Remove them if they were introduced as a part of any issue or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the prepare agent had a different `destFile` in configuration, but accordingly the report had to be configured with a `dataFile`, but this configuration was missing. Once the `dataFile` was added, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed following two lines from `properties` tag

```
<jacoco.ut.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</jacoco.ut.reportPath>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
```

`mvn install -Psonar` by default creates *jacoco.exec* in target directory, so explicit path was not needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For others that met similar problem, here is another possible solution:

Our project was running in a Traditional Chinese version of Windows, and when we checked `prepare-agent` section in maven log, we found that it tried to read the project folder which we put on desktop, through `\桌面\...\project\...` instead of `\Desktop\...\project\...`. I think UTF-8 symbol in paths make Jacoco go weird. We moved the project into other place and the issue was fixed.

TL;DR:
Check `prepare-agent` logs too as `jacoco.exec` was prepared during that.

Answer (score 0):

Another case

-Dtest=CommonUtilTest -DfailIfNoTests=false

using these flag also coverage report doesn't work
I was trying to execute only a certain testcases but that , junits worked but with no coverage report.
Have to run without those flags

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The reason for jacoco to fail was cyrillic letters and spaces in project's absolute path.

You should check your maven output. There should be a line starting with `argLine set to -javaagent:`, and a path following. Check if this path holds any  spaces / non english letters / special symbols.