# Why is jacoco not taking test coverage from azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a pipeline wherein I intend to do the code coverage of my unit tests by JaCoCo. The pipeline is configured and when run it prints the following commands when the agent is being prepared

{"buildfile":"/top/data/agent1/2/s/pom.xml","classfilter":null,"classfilesdirectories":"/top/data/agent1/2/s/target/test-classes/*,/top/data/agent1/2/s/target/classes/*","sourcedirectories":"/top/data/agent1/2/s/src/main/java/*,/top/data/agent1/2/s/src/test/java/*","summaryfile":"/top/data/agent1/2/s/CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.xml","reportdirectory":"/top/data/agent1/2/s/CCReport43F6D5EF","reportbuildfile":"/top/data/agent1/2/s/CCReportPomA4D283EG.xml"}

I can verify that the paths are correct in the command, just that I am using a wild card (but the error remains same while not using them)

I am using a self hosted azure agent. What happens is that unit tests run fine and in the last it prints

Tests run: 1638, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 17
jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report (default-report-vsts) @ MyProject ---
Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

I have tried giving various source and test classes path (like going one directory back or two directories back), the error remains the same.

I am using

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.22.2</version>
```

in my pom.xml and for Jacoco plugin (0.8.4) i have no entry in pom.xml so it seems like Azure devops is injecting the same when I choose Jacoco as code coverage tool.

Comment: Followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373452/skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-error and got it done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373452/skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-error)