# JaCoco through JBehave: Unresolved compilation problems in EmbedderClassLoader

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jbehave

I'm trying to run the JaCoCo cobertura plugin using the JBehave stories as tests. I created a profile to run cobertura, with the command

mvn clean install -P test-coverage

The JBehave tests runs nicelly, but when I try to use the JaCoCo profile, i get the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache cannot be resolved
    ToStringBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
    ToStringBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
    ToStringStyle cannot be resolved to a variable

    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.EmbedderClassLoader.<init>(EmbedderClassLoader.java:11)
    at org.jbehave.mojo.AbstractEmbedderMojo.classLoader(AbstractEmbedderMojo.java:273)
    at org.jbehave.mojo.AbstractEmbedderMojo.newEmbedder(AbstractEmbedderMojo.java:332)
    at org.jbehave.mojo.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.execute(RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.java:15)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

I used this post as a reference: [Getting "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file" upon executing JaCoCo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107375/getting-skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-file-upon-exec)

So my plugin tag is as follow:

```
<!-- JBehave -->
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jbehave.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <!-- <execution>
                <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution> -->
              <execution>
                <id>embeddable-stories</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <includes>
                    <include>${embeddables}</include>
                  </includes>
                  <excludes />
                  <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
                  <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
                  <threads>1</threads>
                  <metaFilters>
                    <metaFilter></metaFilter>
                  </metaFilters>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.