# Unable to run jacoco code coverage tool

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a maven project ([link](https://github.com/yahoo/pulsar/)) and I want to run code coverage on it.

I ran the command `mvn test -Pcoverage jacoco:prepare-agent jacoco:report` on the main project pom file, but the report is not generated. Instead I get a warning saying

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:report (post-test) @ pulsar-discovery-service ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (default-cli) @ pulsar-discovery-service ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/jai1/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.7.201606060606/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/jai1/pulsar/pulsar-discovery-service/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:report (default-cli) @ pulsar-discovery-service ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
```

Can someone suggest how can I generate the code coverage report with this [pom file](https://github.com/yahoo/pulsar/blob/master/pom.xml). I am using apache-maven-3.3.9 and testNG.

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107375/getting-skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-file-upon-exec

Comment: @Ravi - Nope didn't help

Comment: Please show your `maven-surefire-plugin` and `jacoco-maven-plugin` configuration. Also, does your `coverage` profile contain a dependency on `sonar-jacoco-listeners`?

Comment: Entire configuration is in https://github.com/yahoo/pulsar/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 5):

[Your pom.xml](https://github.com/yahoo/pulsar/blob/766e987e9b6f2189c44e679a70891f2bec846af6/pom.xml#L484-L492) contains

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine> -Xmx2G -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8G
        -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

while [JaCoCo documentation for `prepare-agent` goal](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html) states

> If your project already defines VM arguments for test execution, be sure that they will include property defined by JaCoCo.
>
> ... define "argLine" as a Maven property rather than as part of the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin:
>
> ```
>   <properties>
>     <argLine>-your -extra -arguments</argLine>
>   </properties>
>   ...
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>       <!-- no argLine here -->
>     </configuration>
>   </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems like you are missing below line in pom.xml 
<destFile>
   ${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec
</destFile>
```

### Please have look at the below pom :

```
 <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
           <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>prepare-jacoco-4-unit-tests</id>
                      <goals>
                           <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
          <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
         <destFile>
             ${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec
         </destFile>                                             
         <propertyName>jacocoArgLine</propertyName>
         </configuration>
         </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>create-jacoco-reports-4-unit-tests</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
               <configuration>
           <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
          <dataFile>
              ${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec
          </dataFile>
          </configuration>
          </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And then in maven-surefire-plugin following should be defined :

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.17</version>
     <configuration>
         <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
         <argLine>${jacocoArgLine}</argLine>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Tried what you said in "https://github.com/jai1/pulsar/tree/temp" but still no luck

Comment: ok, let me try to clone your project and try locally. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your time 
Just a heads up - the test suite is pretty huge so delete the tests (or keep just one) before running the mvn job else it will take two hours to complete.

 find . -name "*Test.java"  | xargs rm -f

Answer (score 0):

The following is what works for us:

Set up some properties:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <!-- versions below are last ones that are Java 6 compatible -->
    <version.jacoco-agent>0.7.4.201502262128</version.jacoco-agent>
    <jacocoArgLine />
    <surefire.base.argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -Xmx1024m -Djava.awt.headless=true</surefire.base.argLine>
    ...
</properties>
```

and the `coverage` profile:

```
    <profile>
        <id>coverage</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>${surefire.base.argLine} @{jacocoArgLine}</argLine>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below a complete simple demo project showing unit, integration, cucumber tests. The test coverage is shown via Jacoco.

- Multi module project
- Unit test (via mvn clean install)
- Integration test (via mvn clean install -P integration-test)
- **Cucumber tests** (via mvn clean install) - to demo unit/it-testing
- **Jacoco** - test coverage ( both aggregate datafile and aggregate reporting)
- FindBugs - code quality

Enjoy the [sipmle demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git).

Comment: Nice Try - but  Failed to execute goal on project module3: Could not resolve dependencies for project nl.deholtmans:module3:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact nl.deholtmans:module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT I'm not up or downvoting