# Always EOFException with Jacoco exec file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, sonarqube, jacoco

I tried to generate Jacoco reports for Sonarqube. Generating the file jacoco.exec works but using it for Sonarqube OR in Eclipse's EclEmma results in an EOFException (so both implementations are crappy or the generated file is the problem). There are some questions about this problem but no solution (besides not using test coverage).

I created a Spring Boot application and tried to generate a Jacoco test coverage report with Maven. There is no problem in using `mvn test` and a jacoco.exec gets generated in the target folder. But when I try to upload the results to Sonarqube with `mvn sonar:sonar` I always get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project project-name: Unable to read XXX\project-name\target\jacoco.exec: EOFException -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Stacktrace:

```
$ mvn sonar:sonar   -Dsonar.projectKey=...   -Dsonar.host.url=...   -Dsonar.login=... -eX
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: windows
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 6.1
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 6
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 1
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: windows-x86_64
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in NEXUS-URL/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of corporate has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------< project-name >--------------
[INFO] Building project-name 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in NEXUS-URL/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of corporate has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) @ project-name ---
[INFO] User cache: C:\Entwicklung\.sonar\cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 8.0.0
[INFO] Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[WARNING] SonarScanner will require Java 11+ to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=85ms
[INFO] Server id: BF41A1F2-AW34YlpIvdDiua-FIR0_
[INFO] User cache: C:\Entwicklung\.sonar\cache
[INFO] Load/download plugins
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=53ms
[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=96ms
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Process project properties (done) | time=13ms
[INFO] Execute project builders
[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=4ms
[INFO] Project key: project-name
[INFO] Base dir: XXX\project-name
[INFO] Working dir: XXX\project-name\target\sonar
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'project-name'
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'project-name' (done) | time=19ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=275ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=2214ms
[INFO] Indexing files...
[INFO] Project configuration:
[INFO] 25 files indexed
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on module project-name
[INFO] Load metrics repository
[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=60ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 8
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=31ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=23ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 23 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=21ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=4614ms
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 23/23 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=1484ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=7085ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=4ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [XXX\project-name\target\surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=75ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' is deprecated (JaCoCo binary format). 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' should be used instead (JaCoCo XML format). Please check that the JaCoCo plugin is installed on your SonarQube Instance.
[INFO] Analysing XXX\project-name\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping project-name
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.163 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-24T11:04:54+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project project-name: Unable to read XXX\project-name\target\jacoco.exec: EOFException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project project-name: Unable to read XXX\project-name\target\jacoco.exec
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to read XXX\project-name\target\jacoco.exec
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Unable to read XXX\project-name\target\jacoco.exec
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.readJacocoReport (JacocoReportReader.java:72)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.readExecutionData (UnitTestAnalyzer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.analyse (UnitTestAnalyzer.java:102)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.execute (JaCoCoSensor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse (AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1 (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart (ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan (ProjectScanContainer.java:387)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively (ProjectScanContainer.java:383)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart (ProjectScanContainer.java:346)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart (GlobalContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute (Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute (Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute (BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke (IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.execute (Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute (EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute (EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte (DataInputStream.java:267)
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.data.CompactDataInput.readBooleanArray (CompactDataInput.java:63)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readExecutionData (ExecutionDataReader.java:149)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readBlock (ExecutionDataReader.java:115)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read (ExecutionDataReader.java:92)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.readJacocoReport (JacocoReportReader.java:70)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.readExecutionData (UnitTestAnalyzer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.UnitTestAnalyzer.analyse (UnitTestAnalyzer.java:102)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.execute (JaCoCoSensor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse (AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1 (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute (ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart (ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan (ProjectScanContainer.java:387)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively (ProjectScanContainer.java:383)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart (ProjectScanContainer.java:346)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart (GlobalContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute (Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute (Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute (BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke (IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.execute (Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute (EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute (EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm using Jacoco 0.8.5, Sonarqube 8 and Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE on Windows 7.

Update:
One of my colleagues was able without any adjustments to do the Maven build. We had the same Java version and same Maven version. I still don't know the problem and I'm more confused than ever. The only main difference was his OS because he was using Windows 10.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Jacoco 0.8.5, sonar-maven-plugin 3.7.0.1746 and SonarQube 7.5, Maven 3.5.0 and JDK 7.

Answer (score 5):

According to the following GitHub answer https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/980#issuecomment-563091107
the exec binary file was truncated due to the JVM shutdown not gracefully executed, meaning JaCoCO exec binary file is corrupted.
To resolve this exception make sure you shutdown the JVM gracefully i.e. by invoking the JVM shutdown hook.

Comment: How to invoke the hook? Oracle docs say the hooks start automatically on `System.exit()`  and normal termination of the application.  Hooks cannot be directly invoked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about your tests terminating properly, move all your tests except the simplest (such as one against a class that simply manipulates a list or produces random numbers) into a temporary directory outside of your test source code structure.  Verify that you're still getting the error.

If they're now succeeding, re-introduce the risky ones back into your test directory tree piece-meal until it fails again.  Solution by isolation.

**Alternatively**, and this took too much time to discover, it could be that JaCoCo is failing to generate the dump file (`jacoco.exec`) in a timely manner.

*Project tools:* Maven 3.8.6, JDK 11, yes, I'm using JPMS, Surefire-plugin 2.22.2, JaCoCo-plugin 0.8.8, JUnit 5.9.1.

I have only 750 lines of production code in my project, only 10 external dependencies -- it's a very small project and it was timing out.  I thought my configuration was wrong all this time, but Maven was killing the JaCoCo process (forked from Surefire) that creates the dump file before it finished.  `EOFException`?  Absolutely!  I changed my pom to the following:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.22.2</version>
           <configuration>
               ...
               <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>240</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
           </configuration>
       <plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Adding 4 minutes to allow the generator to create the dump file fixed it for me.  There's got to be a better way.  Sadly, as my project grows, I'll have to keep increasing this number.  But at least I have coverage reports now.