# Getting "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file" with Jacoco in VS Code

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I'm using Maven 3.8.3, JUnit 5.4.2, and Jacoco 0.8.2, and I am trying to create test coverage reports.

I have a project with unit tests only, but I can't get reports to run, I'm repeatedly getting the error: Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file when I run:

```
mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent install jacoco:report
```

Here is how my pom is configured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.2</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                  <id>report</id>
                  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <configuration>
    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
  </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas what configuration I'm missing?

Comment: First upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to minimum 2.22.2 ...

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you are providing your custom `argLine` parameter to `maven-surefire-plugin`, you need to make sure that the `@{argLine}` is added to your property. For your xml, it would be like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107375/getting-skipping-jacoco-execution-due-to-missing-execution-data-file-upon-exec) explaining the `argLine` parameter with Jacoco and Maven Surefire Plugin.