# Setting timezone for maven unit tests on Java 8

Tags: java, maven, timezone, java-8, surefire

How do I set the timezone for unit tests in maven surefire on Java 8?

With Java 7 this used to work with `systemPropertyVariables` like in the following configuration, but with Java 8 the tests just use the system timezone.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <user.timezone>UTC</user.timezone>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
```

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Use the full `Etc/UTC` instead of just `UTC` because three-letter time zone abbreviations are considered deprecated since they can cause [confusion](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ThreeLetterTimeZoneID).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

#### Short answer

Java now reads `user.timezone` earlier, before surefire sets the properties in `systemPropertyVariables`. The solution is to set it earlier, using `argLine`:

```
<plugin>
  ...
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine>
```

#### Long answer

Java initializes the default timezone, taking `user.timezone` into account the *first* time it needs it and then caches it in `java.util.TimeZone`. That now happens already when reading a jar file: `ZipFile.getZipEntry` now calls `ZipUtils.dosToJavaTime` which creates a `Date` instance that initializes the default timezone. This is not a surefire-specific problem. Some call it a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1176) in JDK7.  This program used to print the time in UTC, but now uses the system timezone:

```java
import java.util.*;

class TimeZoneTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
    System.out.println(new Date());
  }
}
```

In general, the solution is to specify the timezone on the command line, like `java -Duser.timezone=UTC TimeZoneTest`, or set it programmatically with `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`.

Full'ish [example](https://github.com/SierraGolf/logback/blob/c74cf7cb2aed7e072ee5d59ee9252918aeae5f8b/logback-access/pom.xml):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        ... could specify version, other settings if desired ...
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Uhm, if you use Java 8, why use `Date` at all? Use the new `DateTime`, `LocalDateTime` etc

Comment: @fge That's irrelevant, `new Date()` is just a simple example to be able to compare with Java 7. The new time classes use the same default timezone, so they have exactly the same problem.

Comment: It's weird that `mvn -Duser.timezone=UTC` doesn't work either. Only `<argLine>` works.

Comment: Setting `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` in `@Before` worked for me. argLine didn't not sure why. On junit4.10 and mvn3

Comment: We can use <argLine>-Duser.timezone="Europe/London"</argLine> also

Comment: add user.timezone in  MAVEN_OPTS eg: export MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=GMT+8

Comment: For me this worked. If it works command line but not IntelliJ (and jacoco is also at play) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29975159/32453 or use the @Before workaround from zengr's comment...

Comment: @SanghyunLee That applies the system property to the Maven process. By default, Surefire / Failsafe will run tests in a separate process. See "Forked Test Execution" [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)

Comment: element <argLine> is not allowed?

Comment: WARNING: Be careful not to override the javaagent argLine, or risk spending hours to figure out why jacoco no longer works for instance...

Comment: Use the full `Etc/UTC` instead of just `UTC` because three-letter time zone abbreviations are considered deprecated since they can cause [confusion](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ThreeLetterTimeZoneID).