# How to covert the Time from UTC into Local time in pom.xml?

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to send an Test Email Report with current Date & Time format. I've Used Below code in pom.xml. But the local printing in the subject line. It is printing UTC instead of "GMT 5.30+"(India). Please help me to resolve the issue.

${maven.build.timestamp.format}  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

In the Email Code subject line:

Sanity Test Automation Report: ${timestamp}

But it Printing UTC time instead of Indian local time.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What Maven plugin(s) are you using for this?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe, Please help me

Comment: Are you running this locally or on the build server? If on the build server, is the server set to the correct time zone?

Comment: No I'm using maven to run this test

Comment: Can you help me to change the maven server time zone. By default it is in UTC. I've tried several ways, But no luck

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466218/setting-timezone-for-maven-unit-tests-on-java-8 can help ?

Comment: Tried <user.timezone>IST</user.timezone>. But not working

Comment: @SatyaSandeepReddyGudimetla, did you even try the given example?!
Nobody is going to program this for you, you have to try by yourself whether the suggested solution is going to work or not.

Comment: Hi @metters, I have tried all the possible links available in stackoverflow related this issue. After only i have posted this for new suggestions. In the above link, I've already tried that one also, but the time zone is not changing from UTC.