# Gatling: Parsing log file - OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, sbt, heap-memory, load-testing, gatling

I start sbt with -Xmx4G options specified:

```
java -Xms2G -Xmx4G -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\sbt-launch.jar"
```

But at the end of the test run, Gatling fails with `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

```
Parsing log file(s)...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid17300.hprof ...Only 1223s
Dumping heap to java_pid17300.hprof ...Heap dump file created [1320803380 bytes in 4.554 secs]
[error] Uncaught exception when running test.FeLoadTest: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

It is seen from the error message that the heap is only `1320803380 bytes ~> 1.2G`. But as I have set Xmx to 4G, I do not understand why this `OutOfMemoryError` happens - the allocated memory should be enough. Any help to overcome this error while parsing the test log file is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the answer - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392180/karate-gatling-how-to-resolve-java-heap-space-outofmemoryerror)

The solution is to increase memory for gatling-plugin, not for sbt. In `build.sbt` file need to add `javaOptions`:

```
# this is build.sbt file

lazy val root = Project("testing-gatling", file("."))
  .enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
  .settings(...)
  .settings(javaOptions in Gatling := overrideDefaultJavaOptions("-Xms1024m", "-Xmx4096m"))
```

It works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to launch sbt and set parameters is to use the script.

Please try:

```
sbt -J-Xmx4G test
```