# Apache environment build Issues-in fe-core builing steap

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, build-environment

## In stage fe-core building failured, and the error location is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error`

```
[INFO] Doris FE Project Parent POM ........................ SUCCESS [  1.792 s]
[INFO] fe-common .......................................... SUCCESS [ 15.683 s]
[INFO] spark-dpp .......................................... SUCCESS [ 12.169 s]
[INFO] fe-core ............................................ FAILURE [01:35 min] <=====
[INFO] hive-udf ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] java-udf ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-27T12:50:04+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[2]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/commons-io-2.6.jar
constituent[3]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[4]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[5]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar
constituent[6]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/jansi-2.4.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
constituent[8]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[9]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar
constituent[10]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-artifact-3.8.6.jar
constituent[11]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-builder-support-3.8.6.jar
constituent[12]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-compat-3.8.6.jar
constituent[13]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-core-3.8.6.jar
constituent[14]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-embedder-3.8.6.jar
constituent[15]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-model-3.8.6.jar
constituent[16]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-model-builder-3.8.6.jar
constituent[17]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.8.6.jar
constituent[18]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.6.jar
constituent[19]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar
constituent[20]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.3.jar
constituent[21]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar
constituent[22]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.6.jar
constituent[23]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar
constituent[24]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.3.jar
constituent[25]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.6.3.jar
constituent[26]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-settings-3.8.6.jar
constituent[27]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.8.6.jar
constituent[28]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar
constituent[29]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar
constituent[30]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar
constituent[31]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar
constituent[32]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
constituent[33]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[34]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar
constituent[35]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar
constituent[36]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/plexus-utils-3.3.1.jar
constituent[37]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
constituent[38]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/wagon-file-3.5.1.jar
constituent[39]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/wagon-http-3.5.1-shaded.jar
constituent[40]: file:/D:/Aaron/Plug-ins/apache-maven-3.8.6/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.5.1.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Error was thrown while processing D:\Aaron\Apache\fe\fe-core
\src\main\java\org\apache\doris\httpv2\rest\manager\HttpUtils.java
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.processFiles(Checker.java:313)
        at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process(Checker.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.exec.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultC
heckstyleExecutor.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(CheckstyleViolationC
heckMojo.java:545)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:
137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilde
r.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilde
r.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(Single
ThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ArrayPredictionContext.<init>(ArrayPredictionContext.java:24)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.merge(PredictionContext.java:172)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNConfigSet.add(ATNConfigSet.java:155)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1529)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1496)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1586)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:
1513)
```

This issue seems like java bug?  but I have no idea about java

I'm following Apache tutorial to buil environment, but still.. QAQ

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an environment variable via the following command to increase the maven allocated heap memory:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx3000m"
```

MAVEN_OPTS environment variable: This variable contains parameters used to start up the JVM running Maven and can be used to supply additional options to it.

You can change 3000 to what you require.
If it doesn't work, visit the following link too:
[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066424/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-in-maven?rq=1)